# How to understand the definition of Killing form?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, trace

Define the matrix commutator $\text{ad}_X$ as
$$\text{ad}_XY=[X,Y]=XY-YX$$
where $X,Y\in\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra associated to Lie group $G$.

Then on Lie group $G$, the Killing form is defined as
$$B=trace(\text{ad}_X\cdot\text{ad}_Y)$$

What I don't understand is how to get the trace of $\text{ad}_X\cdot\text{ad}_Y$ . In my opinion, $\text{ad}_X$ and $\text{ad}_Y$ are just mappings, how can we get the trace of one mapping?

Could you please give some easy examples to explain this definition? For example, on Lie group $SE(2)$, how to get $B$?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem - the trace is defined for any endomorphism of a finite-dimensional vector space, and $\text{ad}_X\circ\text{ad}_Y$ is one such, defined on the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that the $trace$ is defined only for matrix. Now I know its other definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear map $ad(x)\colon y\mapsto [x,y]$ has a matrix associated, with respect to the basis of the Lie algebra, as any linear map has a matrix associated with respect to the basis of the vector space. So we can multiply the two matrices $ad(x)$ and $ad(y)$ and take its trace.

For example, let $L=\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$ with vector space basis $(e,f,h)$
and Lie brackets $[e,f]=h, [h,e]=2e, [h,f]=-2f$. Then the matrices for
$ad(e)$, $ad(f)$ and $ad(h)$ are given as follows:

$$
ad(e)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\;
ad(f)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\;
ad(h)=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$